# Blender 2.83 Aling Objects MISSING

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-view, interface, transforms

recently started using Blender 2.83 and just now I noticed the Align Objects is missing.
When I select one object and then the other one and then go Object->Transform from the menu bar at the top,
it's missing. There's no Align Objects as it used to be. Instead, there's "Align Selected to Active", but when I do that the menu that used to pop up in the left down corner with more options is missing. I tried with search and it still doesn't find it. I'm I blind or the tool has been moved to someplace else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found what causes the problem. For some reason I had the "Align Tools" add-on activated. I don't know if I activated it by accident or something, but this is what was causing the "Align Objects" option to disappear and to be replaced with another tool. Hopefully, other people can find this post if they have the same issue. [image]

Comment: This solved the problem for me. I also had to restart Blender.

Answer (score 2):

This is a screenshot from my version of blender (2.83). It seems to be here, if it's not, try re-downloading blender:

[image: Align]

Comment: Oh sorry I just saw you said its 2.83. Probably need to reinstall.

Comment: Align tools look weird - there is no option to select aligning centers or other parts of object. "Advanced" button does nothing too. I can't figure out if something is wrong in the latest Blender or I am doing something wrong.. But I can't align a bottom part of box to a plane.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 3.1.2 Align Tools can be found at the bottom of the right Sidebar menu  (open by pressing N key).