# Where did the the Align selected to active go in 3.0?

Tags: transform-orientation

In previous version of Blender this option would give the ability to centre the selected object to X Y or Z axis. In Blender 3.0 when you chose the objects they just align with each other in the centre. So what's the best method to get have this option like the old Blender?

This is from previous version of Blender:

https://ibb.co/LgGpsXh

[image]

Comment: You can still choose *Object > Transform > Align Objects*, then in the *Operator* box choose the axis and the mode (*Active* if this is what your want)

Comment: Hi Moonboots, where has this Operator box gone to? It use to be down the left hand side, now I cannot locate it. And When you say align objects its not in my menu, only that new option which is the: Align selected to active.

Comment: ok that's weird, I can't tell because it works fine with my Blender 3, I hope someone will understand

Comment: Is this the operator box you're referring to? https://ibb.co/fvNLqjJ

Comment: here: https://zupimages.net/up/22/07/yle4.jpg and https://zupimages.net/up/22/07/ec0n.jpg

Comment: Is that 3.0 you're on? That's weird! I don't have those options in my Blender 3.0. I had those options in my previous versions of Blender.

Comment: Ok I found the solution here, its the Addon which deactivates Blender Align objects Operator box: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185138/blender-2-83-aling-objects-missing

Comment: oh ok so that explains your problem